# how to grant a user Administrative rights using phpMyAdmin4

Tags: php, mysql

I'm hosting a forum board using PHPBB, unfortunately I had lost the password to the board and the domain I used for the e-mail of that administrator's account was also lost. I've changed the email admin's address from the config.php file but that didn't change a thing, I've registered with a new user recently and now my question is: how to grant a PHPBB user Administrative rights on a forum board through or MySQL OR phpMyAdmin4? Which field from what table should I modify
I'm pretty much new to all this so please make the answers as details as possible, (preferably with picture)

Anticipating thanks.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for things that involve programming. You're probably better of on [su].

Comment: @Siguza is correct; this is more of a phpBB problem. I don't have a phpBB environment to play with, but if you're comfortable working in a database, you can dig into the tables and their values here: https://wiki.phpbb.com/Tables. It appears to be a very useful resource.